# How do I correctly use enum within a class?

Tags: variables, class

I am trying to set the status of an object from a private enum and I'm not sure how to get the private member to the public version in the constructor, and I'm pretty sure I should not be using `byte` in the constructor when it's an enum.

Also, I'm not sure if I should even have the values of the enum inside the header at all. Here is my code:

.h

```
class CandleRack
{
  public:

    CandleRack(byte candleRackStatus);
    ~CandleRack();
    void begin();
    void pushButton();
    void selectRandomCandle();
    void turnOnCandle(byte candlePosition);
    void burnCandlesForMs();
    void fadeOutCandle(byte candlePosition);


  private:
    Bounce *_debouncePushButton;
    byte _pushButtonPin; 
    enum _candleRackStatus
    {
      inactive = 0,
      candlesOn = 1,
      rewardAnimation = 2,
      tweetArrived = 3,
      partyMode = 4,      
    };
    byte _candlePosition;
    byte _candleStatus[NUM_LEDS];
    elapsedMillis _candleTimeElapsed[NUM_LEDS];
    unsigned int _candleOnForMs;
};
```

.cpp

```
CandleRack::CandleRack(byte candleRackStatus)
{
  _candleRackStatus = candleRackStatus;
  _debouncePushButton = NULL;
}
```

in the sketch

```
CandleRack MyCandleRack(0);
```

error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
_candleRackStatus = candleRackStatus;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Might be more of a programming question as an Arduino question. I've heard that ENUM's are specifically useful when dealing with `switch-case` statements, since you can define a "default" case.

Comment: You can define a 'default' case on a switch statement without needing an enum, but for me it will help the code be more usable as you can give each case a name and not just a number.

Comment: SHouldn't `CandleRack MyCandleRack(0);` be `CandleRack MyCandleRack(inactive);` or maybe CandleRack::inactive. My C++ is a bit rusty (very rusty). Also, in the interests of program readability the enum would be useful outside the class otherwise you're just assigning a bunch of numbers.

Comment: The enum gives the object its properties so my logic tells me it should be a part of the class, it's also a private member so it's properties are hidden from all of the other classes I will be adding. You're right about `MyCandleRack(inactive);` though.

Comment: Hmm, you're true on the default thing. But I can vaguely remember my prof being "mad" at me for using defines instead of enums, since your compiler could check if all enums are handled in your switch-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two separate issues here.

First of all your enum isn't available as a variable. 
By declaring it as a private type within your class the enum can't be used outside of that class.

This forces a user of that class to handle unintended calls like (attention, *bug*):

```
CandleRack(255);
```

which can make code harder to read (and debugging more difficult, since it wouldn't be detected by the compiler).

Second of all you try to directly assign a byte *value* to an enum *type*. This will be rejected by the compiler and/or cause runtime errors later (depending on compiler settings).

I recommend that you declare the enum type so that it is accessible directly via the header file:

.h

```
enum CandleRackStatus {
    inactive = 0,
    candlesOn = 1,
    rewardAnimation = 2,
    tweetArrived = 3,
    partyMode = 4,      
};

class CandleRack
{
  public:

    CandleRack(CandleRackStatus candleRackStatus);
    ~CandleRack();
    void begin();
    void pushButton();
    void selectRandomCandle();
    void turnOnCandle(byte candlePosition);
    void burnCandlesForMs();
    void fadeOutCandle(byte candlePosition);

  private:
    Bounce *_debouncePushButton;
    CandleRackStatus _candleRackStatus;
    byte _pushButtonPin; 
    byte _candlePosition;
    byte _candleStatus[NUM_LEDS];
    elapsedMillis _candleTimeElapsed[NUM_LEDS];
    unsigned int _candleOnForMs;
};
```

Now you can instantiate your class while using the correct enum type as the parameter.

.ino

```
CandleRack MyCandleRack(CandleRackStatus::inactive);
```

Within your implementation you can now directly store the constructor parameter in the private variable, the compiler will make sure it's always of the correct enum type:

.cpp

```
CandleRack::CandleRack(CandleRackStatus candleRackStatus) {
    _candleRackStatus = candleRackStatus;
    // rest of your initialisiation goes here
}
```

As an added bonus, there's the possibility to use a couple of C++ language features that will make your implementation easier:

- [a default parameter value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument#Default_arguments_in_C.2B.2B)
- [an initializer (list)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)#Initializer_list)

.h

```
class 
{
  public:
    CandleRack(CandleRackStatus candleRackStatus = CandleRackStatus::inactive);
    // [...]
}
```

.cpp

```
CandleRack::CandleRack(CandleRackStatus candleRackStatus) : _candleRackStatus(candleRackStatus) {
    // rest of your initializiation goes here
}
```

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why you have Capitalized the name CandleRackStatus. I thought an enum was just a variable and nothing like a class or struct. I think it's confusing to treat it like a class (with naming conventions) ...

Comment: last question, when I actually want to change the status of the CandleRack, do I do `_candleRackStatus = candlesOn` ?

Comment: Re: Capitalized, that's a matter of taste and what school of programming you come from. I recommend treating enums like types, because they are. And in most C++ styles types get a capitalized name. See https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Enumerator_Names for reference, also a good read as a whole.

Comment: Re: changing the status, the identifier `candlesOn` is defined within the type declaration of the enum. So in order to access it you would qualify it with the type name: `CandleRackStatus::candlesOn`. That's called *static access* and the `::` operator works on all type properties that are public and static (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090949/accessing-to-enum-values-by-in-c). So you would change the status using `_candleRackStatus = CandleRackStatus::candlesOn`.

Comment: We've discussed simplification of names before, so if these expressions are too lengthy or confusing, just choose shorter names for types and variables.

Answer (score 0):

How about this refactoring?

```
class CandleRack
{
  public:
    enum status_t
    {
      inactive = 0,
      candlesOn = 1,
      rewardAnimation = 2,
      tweetArrived = 3,
      partyMode = 4,      
    };    
    CandleRack(status_t status = inactive);
    ~CandleRack();
    void begin();
    void pushButton();
    void selectRandomCandle();
    void turnOnCandle(byte candlePosition);
    void burnCandlesForMs();
    void fadeOutCandle(byte candlePosition);

  private:
    Bounce *_debouncePushButton;
    byte _pushButtonPin;
    status_t _candleRackStatus;
    byte _candlePosition;
    byte _candleStatus[NUM_LEDS];
    elapsedMillis _candleTimeElapsed[NUM_LEDS];
    unsigned int _candleOnForMs;
};
```

And in a sketch with either the default setting (inactive)

```
CandleRack MyCandleRack;
```

or explicit

```
CandleRack MyCandleRack(CandleRack::candlesOn);
```

Cheers!

Comment: It seems this answer compiles the gist of my answer into a code-only post (see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: Yes It does a bit. If you could add some of these suggestions to your post I think that would make it a great answer. Especially as this shows how I could use the enum as a public member and not outside of the class - which in my mind, makes it more understandable.

Comment: But also thanks to Mikael for this post too, it also helps my understanding of how to use enums.

Comment: In this example where is `status` coming from? `status_t status = inactive`

Comment: `status` is an alternative naming to your `candleRackStatus`. Simpler names can increase readability. Since you only pass one parameter, you don't really need to qualify it in more detail than neccessary, so it's probably a good idea to simplify. :) I've updated my answer to explain the use of the enum type and a default parameter value.

Comment: Hmm, I find descriptive names more readable and other elements of my sketch will also have a status (even of this object - music status, animation status etc) so I think it's important for me not to rename. I'm also unsure of where status_t comes from, what is the _t ?